# What is the quickest way to store attachments in an outlook mailbox mails?

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

Suppose i have my mailbox configured and i have a special folder for mails with attachments in outlook 2007. What i want to do is 
i. either configure outlook to save the attachment of mails coming in a specified folder (Mails with Attachments) to specific folder in my computer drive in a desired folder

ii. Or if i can write some macro or script to copy those all to my computer location. If so can you please give me quick overview or refer me some where.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will save attachments to a directory automatically. Use Outlook rules to run this macro automatically on each incoming message.

```
Sub AutoSaveAttachment(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olAtt As Attachment
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FIleNamewithDate As String
    Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\"

    If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
            Set olAtt = Item.Attachments(i)
            olAtt.SaveAsFile FILE_PATH & olAtt.FileName


        Next i
    End If

    Set olAtt = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This subroutine will save all attachments found in a user specified Outlook folder to a user specified directory on the file system. It also updates each message with a link to the purged files.

It also contains extra comments to help highlight how the .Delete method will shrink Attachment containers dynamically (search for "~~" in the comments).

This macro is only tested on Outlook 2010.

```
' ------------------------------------------------------------
' Requires the following references:
'
' Visual Basic for Applications
' Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library
' OLE Automation
' Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
' Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation
' ------------------------------------------------------------

Public Sub SaveOLFolderAttachments()

  ' Ask the user to select a file system folder for saving the attachments
  Dim oShell As Object
  Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  Dim fsSaveFolder As Object
  Set fsSaveFolder = oShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please Select a Save Folder:", 1)
  If fsSaveFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  ' Note:  BrowseForFolder doesn't add a trailing slash

  ' Ask the user to select an Outlook folder to process
  Dim olPurgeFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Set olPurgeFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
  If olPurgeFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  ' Iteration variables
  Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim att As Outlook.attachment
  Dim sSavePathFS As String
  Dim sDelAtts As String

  For Each msg In olPurgeFolder.Items

    sDelAtts = ""

    ' We check each msg for attachments as opposed to using .Restrict("[Attachment] > 0")
    ' on our olPurgeFolder.Items collection.  The collection returned by the Restrict method
    ' will be dynamically updated each time we remove an attachment.  Each update will
    ' reindex the collection.  As a result, it does not provide a reliable means for iteration.
    ' This is why the For Each loops will not work.
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

      ' This While loop is controlled via the .Delete method
      ' which will decrement msg.Attachments.Count by one each time.
      While msg.Attachments.Count > 0

        ' Save the file
        sSavePathFS = fsSaveFolder.Self.Path & "\" & msg.Attachments(1).FileName
        msg.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile sSavePathFS

        ' Build up a string to denote the file system save path(s)
        ' Format the string according to the msg.BodyFormat.
        If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & vbCrLf & "<file://" & sSavePathFS & ">"
        Else
            sDelAtts = sDelAtts & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" & sSavePathFS & "'>" & sSavePathFS & "</a>"
        End If

        ' Delete the current attachment.  We use a "1" here instead of an "i"
        ' because the .Delete method will shrink the size of the msg.Attachments
        ' collection for us.  Use some well placed Debug.Print statements to see
        ' the behavior.
        msg.Attachments(1).Delete

      Wend

      ' Modify the body of the msg to show the file system location of
      ' the deleted attachments.
      If msg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        msg.Body = msg.Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts
      Else
        msg.HTMLBody = msg.HTMLBody & "<p></p><p>" & "Attachments Deleted:  " & Date & " " & Time & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Saved To:  " & vbCrLf & sDelAtts & "</p>"
      End If

      ' Save the edits to the msg.  If you forget this line, the attachments will not be deleted.
      msg.Save

    End If

  Next

End Sub
```